# JsonSlurper execution failure

Tags: groovy, jsonslurper

I am trying to use JsonSlurper to input variables from different files. But it is failing at second execution. Could someone help me?

It's failing from step `Jenkins_File_Path = readFile ( "${Local_Path_App}" + "/Jenkinsfile" )`

**Main.groovy**

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

Global_Settings_Path = readFile ("${Main_Local_Path}" + "/Config/GlobalSettings_Java.json" )
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def GlobalVariables = jsonSlurper.parseText(Global_Settings_Path)

Jenkins_File_Path = readFile ( "${Local_Path_App}" + "/Jenkinsfile" )
def jsonSlurper1 = new JsonSlurper()
def json = jsonSlurper1.parseText(Jenkins_File_Path)
```

**GlobalSettings_Java.json**

```
{
    "LOB": {
        "SVN_Config_Path": "testpath",
        "Local_Path_LOB": "test",
    }
}
```

**Jenkinsfile**

```
{
    "BUILD_INFO": {
        "Build_Type" : "Maven",
    }
}
```

**Error Logs**

> java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
>       at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1785)
>       at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1362)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor469.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:271)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
>       at java.util.TreeMap.writeObject(TreeMap.java:2438)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor475.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:271)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
>       at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:132)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:433)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:412)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:357)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:78)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:236)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:224)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:63)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
>       at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: an exception which occurred:
>       in field locals
>       in field caller
>       in field e
>       in field program
>       in field threads
>       in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@7abaf96e
>   Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Try using `JsonSlurperClassic` instead. I find that the `LazyMap` class that `JsonSlurper` uses under the surface is often more trouble than it is worth. `JsonSlurperClassic` uses a regular `HashMap`.

Comment: Great. I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you @BalRog. It worked fined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Change `JsonSlurper` to `JsonSlurperClassic`.

**Answer:**

The `LazyMap` class used under the surface by `JsonSlurper` is frequently the source of this and many other problems. The older version of `JsonSlurper`, found in current releases as `JsonSlurperClassic`, uses a regular, serializable Java `HashMap` for those purposes, and hence is not prone to the same sorts of problems.

Comment: works like a charm. JsonSlurper sucks for jenkins-pipeline...

Comment: If the individual who voted this answer down would be so kind as to explain the problem with it I would greatly appreciate it.