# JsonSlurper parseText exception in Groovy Script: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to [C

Tags: groovy, jsonslurper

I want to parse Json in Groovy, but it throwns exception, don't known what's wrong with my code, need some help

**[ENV:]**

jdk-9.0.4

ide:idea

lang:Groovy

Exception as below:
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3$1 (file:/C:/Users/hhbst/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.3.11/f6b34997d04c1538ce451d3955298f46fdb4dbd4/groovy-all-2.3.11.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to [C

```
at groovy.json.internal.FastStringUtils$StringImplementation$1.toCharArray(FastStringUtils.java:88)
at groovy.json.internal.FastStringUtils.toCharArray(FastStringUtils.java:175)
at groovy.json.internal.BaseJsonParser.parse(BaseJsonParser.java:103)
at groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseText(JsonSlurper.java:208)
at groovy.json.JsonSlurper$parseText.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at com.hypers.test.apitest.util.JsonUtilTest.JsonParaTest(JsonUtilTest.groovy:20)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Process finished with exit code -1

```
@Test
void JsonParaTest(){
    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def object = jsonSlurper.parseText('{ "name": "John Doe" }')

    assert object.name == 'John Doe'
}
```

Comment: Which version of groovy?

Comment: groovy -v
Groovy Version: 2.5.6 JVM: 9.0.4 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 10

Comment: Looks like this error https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/GROOVY-7716 which it says was fixed. You seem to be using 2.3.11 in your tests (from the stacktrace) could you try updating your dependency?

Comment: Thanks a lot, update dependency version from 2.3.11 to 2.5.6 wroks for me

Comment: compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.5.6'

Comment: Cool news! Added it as an answer for people in the future 

Comment: This could also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41305311/jsonslurper-execution-failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a bug with old versions of groovy when Java 9 came out

https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/GROOVY-7716

Updating the groovy dependency will fix it